# Access Swagger UI using external IP address instead of localhost

Tags: c#, .net, iis, swagger

I have a website in IIS using Swagger that I would like to access externally, as in not on the local machine.  I've assigned it port 44363 and the URL http://localhost:44363/swagger/index.html works just fine when remoted into the server.

However if I try the external IP for the server i.e. HTTP://xx.xx.xx.xx:44363 it does not work.  I am new to Swagger so I'm not sure if it can even be accessed externally or if I am missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Is the port open in the firewall? What happens if you ping the external IP?

Comment: It's on a simple AWS Windows Server instance.  The external IP works for a website set up on IIS, port 80 for HTTP traffic, but when I try to access the swagger URL using the port I defined, 44363, it doesn't work.  However localhost:44363 does work.

Comment: Sure, it sounds like a firewall issue ^^

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  I had to add an inbound rule for the AWS instance to allow inbound on 44363 and then add a rule in Windows Firewall to allow the same.  Thanks for the responses!